# Adding NUMA nodes to a QEMU VM

Tags: batch-file, virtualization, qemu, kvm

As of right now I have a batch script that runs my VM that looks like the following:

```
@echo off
set "QEMUDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\qemu"
set "QEMUBIN=qemu-system-x86_64.exe"

start "QEMU" %QEMUDIR%\%QEMUBIN% ^
        -smp 2 -numa node,nodeid=0 -numa node,nodeid=1 ^
        -drive file=hda.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -m 2G  ^
        -L Bios -boot menu=on -rtc base=localtime,clock=host ^
        -parallel none -serial none -name centos -no-acpi -no-hpet ^
        -no-reboot -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd -usb ^
        -device e1000,netdev=user.0 ^
        -netdev user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

But after the VM is created, it seems like it's ignoring my arguments to include 2 NUMA nodes. I ran the command *lscpu* and got the following output:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            6
Model:                 6
Model name:            QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3192.660
BogoMIPS:              0.02
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Flags:                 fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca 
                       cmov pat mse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx 
                       lm nopl pni cx16 hypervisor lahf_lm svm 3dnowprefetch 
                       vmmcall
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your machine actually have multiple NUMA nodes or are you trying to fake it?

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm trying to fake it.

Comment: Didn't know you could use a forward slash as a continuation character in batch files.

Comment: @Squashman I should've specified that I added that for clarity, it doesn't actually work like that.

Comment: For your reference you can write your code like this: `start "QEMU" %QEMUDIR%\%QEMUBIN% ^`. You can then continue to put each line of your code on a separate line as long as you end it with a caret. `-smp 2 -numa node,nodeid=0 -numa node,nodeid=1 ^`

Comment: @Squashman thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

`-numa node,nodeid=0 -numa node,nodeid=1` is no longer a valid command option for QEMU. For anyone who wants to try NUMA emulation with QEMU, try this:

```bash
-m 8G -smp cpus=4 \
-object memory-backend-ram, size=4G,id=m0 \
-object memory-backend-ram, size=4G,id=m1 \
-numa node,memdev=m0,cpus=0-1,nodeid=0 \
-numa node,memdev=m1,cpus=2-3,nodeid=1
```